# How to get subject, messageId with pub/sub gmail?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a `GCP` `Pub/Sub` subscription and topic to receive notifications from my `gmail` inbox. It does indeed work and I get a message on my server when a new email arrives. The problem is that I want to get more information, such as the subject, and the content of the email. But I don't know how to do it, if I try to use:

```
google.gmail("v1").users.messages.get({ id: message.id, userId: 'me', format: 'full' });
```

But I get error 404

```
function listenForMessages() {
  const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
  try {
    const subscription = pubSubClient.subscription("mysub_",);


    let messageCount = 0;
    const messageHandler = async message => {
      console.log(`Received message ${message.id}:`);
      console.log(`\tData: ${message.data}`);
     
      const m = await google.gmail("v1").users.messages.get({ id: message.id, userId: 'me', format: 'full' });
      
      console.log(m)

      messageCount += 1;
      message.ack();
    };


    subscription.on('message', messageHandler);

    setTimeout(() => {
      subscription.removeListener('message', messageHandler);
      console.log(`${messageCount} message(s) received.`);
    }, timeout * 1000);

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("MY ERROR", error)
  }
}

const watchUserGmail = async () => {
  const request = {
    'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
    'topicName': 'mytopic_',
  }
  
  google.gmail("v1").users.watch({ userId: 'me', requestBody: request })
    .then((res) => res)
    .catch((err) => err)
```

}

How can I bring that extra information into the message I get from Pub/Sub?

Comment: Does this [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61108037/) and [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722052/) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

PubSub will notify a Cloud Function that an email has arrived.  Your Cloud Function will then need to List the emails in the folder with `gmail.users.messages.list` and then Get the contents of each email with `gmail.users.messages.get`.  PubSub event data will not have email content.

Here is an example:

```
async function getMessages(auth) {

  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
  const res = await gmail.users.messages.list ({
      userId: 'foo@bar.com',
      labelIds: ['Label_99999'], 
  });

  const messages = res.data.messages || [];

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    for (var message of messages) {
    const msg = await gmail.users.messages.get ({
      userId: 'foo@bar.com',
      id: message.id,
      format: 'full'
    });

    let msgSubject = '';
    const msgHeaders = msg.data.payload.headers;
    for (var header of msgHeaders) {
      if (header.name === 'Subject') {
        msgSubject = header.value;
      }
    }

    const msgData = msg.data.payload.parts[0].body.data  
    const decoded = await decodeBase64(msgData);
    const msgSnippet = msg.data.snippet || '';
    const msgId = msg.data.id || '';

    } 
  }
}

async function decodeBase64(data) {
  const buff = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');  
  const text = buff.toString('utf-8');
  return text;
}
```

Your watcher should include a parameter to the topic which is firing the Cloud Function:

```
async function watchUser(auth) {
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    const res = await gmail.users.watch ({
        userId: 'foo@bar.com',
        topicName: 'projects/yourproject/topics/your-gmail-topic',
        labelIds: ['Label_99999'],
        labelFilterBehavior: 'include'
    });
    console.log(res);
}
```